# How to destroy Gstreamer RTSP Server Object without exiting main application

Tags: python, rtsp, python-gstreamer

I'm creating a GstRTSPServer, and associating a service i.e. port to it using `GstRtspServer.RTSPServer.set_service()`. Now I want to destroy or kill the server so as to free the port, but without exiting my main application, so that port can be reused. How can I do the same without exiting my main application.

P.S.: I referred to [Free Desktop Docs](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-rtsp-server/html/GstRTSPServer.html) but couldn't find a method for the same. I'm using python bindings for the same.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending more time with `RTSP Server documentation`. I figured out that, although there's no associated method to destroy `RTSP Server`. It can be done by unreferencing the `GObject.Maincontext()` instance I'm attaching the server to.

So, `context.unref()`, frees the associated port with server, without exiting my main application.

Comment: As per an experiment I just ran it looks like you can also call g_object_unref() on the server to destroy it.